# matlab fprintf to handle *.c files

Tags: matlab, printf

All I want is to read a *.c file, remove the header, change the header and save the file of course in *.c format. I used  "fprintf", the problem is in the *.c file there is some printf with "\n", and the fprintf interpretes it like a new line :(, I ended up with a broken *.c file.
Is there a way to handle *.c files with matlab commands ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have read the file, you should replace the `\` character with `\\`, which will be converted back to `\` when writing again to file. `strrep` is great for this:

```
str = 'a\nb';
str = strrep(str,'\','\\');
fprintf(str)

a\nb
```

(note that `fprintf` without file identifier prints to command line. Very useful for debugging)

Comment: There is a typo in fprintf(str).

Comment: Thank you, but what about %s, %i, ... now i have a problem with those stuff, any clue !!!!!...

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass user-provided data as the format string, which will be interpreted.  Instead, pass it as a data argument.  Something like this should work:

```
fprintf(file_id, '%s', the_c_source_code);
```